# Where the `l-pac` abrreviation for `list-packeages defined`?

Tags: package

Recent versions of emacs come with package.el built in and provide the abbreviation `M-x l-pac`. However, `l-pac` is not recognized by `smex` or `helm-M-x`. `M-: (l-pac)` also does not work and the help functions do not seem to know about `l-pac` either, so it does not seem to be a an emacs function.

Where/How is `l-pac` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`l-pac` is not a defined abbreviation. Completion for it is provided; that's all.

This comes from user option **`completion-styles`**, which you can customize. The default value (in Emacs 25.1, for example) is `(basic partial-completion emacs22)`, which means try to complete input using, first, *basic* completion, then, *partial* completion, and finally, *emacs22* completion.

It is `partial-completion` that is completing `l-pac` as you see. See the Emacs manual, node [Completion Styles](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Styles.html).  There you see this:

> `partial-completion`
>
> ```
> This aggressive completion style divides the minibuffer text into
>  words separated by hyphens or spaces, and completes each word
>  separately.  (For example, when completing command names, `em-l-m`
>  completes to `emacs-lisp-mode`.)
>
>  Furthermore, a `*` in the minibuffer text is treated as a
>  “wildcard”—it matches any character at the corresponding position
>  in the completion alternative.
> ```

Perhaps `smex` and `helm-M-x` do not support this kind of completion? Or perhaps you need to look at their doc/help to see how they support it.

`M-: (l-pac)` does not work because `l-pac` is not a defined function.  But if you use `M-: (l-pac TAB` then it should be completed OK to `(list-packages`. (You then need to add `)`.)